# Find last occurrence of string

Tags: notepad++

I want to find the last occurrence of a string in a large text file in Windows. Is there a way to do this using Notepad++ (also do suggest methods beyond Notepad++ if you know a better method)?

I don't want to install any add-on or anything else, if possible.

Comment: Go to the end and search backwards? (Click on "Direction |Up" in the Find dialog box.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just press Ctrl+F or from the Menu - Search -> Find
and then type your string in search field.
In direction choose Up, and it will start from the end.(Make sure you haven't point your mouse anywhere on the text before all this, or it is before the first character in the file.)

[image: Notepad++ Find&Replace bottom-up]

Comment: Notepad v7.5.4 has a new option- "Backward direction" instead of two "Up" and "Down" options.